# Let $f(a) = \frac{13+a}{3a+7}$ where $a$ is restricted to positive integers. What is the maximum value of $f(a)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, functions, optimization, maxima-minima

Let $f(a) = \frac{13+a}{3a+7}$ where $a$ is restricted to positive integers. What is the maximum value of $f(a)$?

I tried graphing but it didn't help.  Could anyone answer?  Thanks!

Comment: You can try converting it in form: $x + \frac{y}{3a+7}$, where $x$ and $y$ are some real numbers. It will be easy after that.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
   f(a)
   &= \dfrac{a+13}{3a+7} \\
   &= \dfrac 13 \dfrac{3a+39}{3a+7} \\
   &= \dfrac 13 \left(1 + \dfrac{32}{3a+7} \right) \\
\end{align}

This implies that $f(a)$ is strictly decreasing for positive integers.

Hence the maximum value must be $f(1) = \dfrac 75$

Answer (score 2):

$f'(a)=-\frac{32}{(3a+7)^2}<0$ so $f$ is strictly decreasing for $a>-\frac73$. So $f(1)>f(2)>f(3)>...$

Comment: So the answer's $1$?

Comment: So the answer is $f(1)=\frac{14}{10}=\frac75$

Answer (score 0):

I plotted the graph and it show two branches, as you are limiting it to positive values of $a$ it is the right hand branch which is relevant. This shows as crossing the $y-axis$ at the point where $a=0$ and thereafter the curve is decreasing towards the $x-axis$. so putting $a=0$ gives the max value as $13/7$. If you further limit it to positive integer values of $x$ then this occurs for $x=1$ to give a max value of 14/10.

Comment: Just a quick amendment, $0$ is not positive and so we should set $a=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @StevenGregory's answer, which is more than satisfactory:

Since $f(a)=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{32}{a+7/3}$, we can see that it's got the same graph as that of $y=\frac{1}{a}$ but:

1. Translated left by $7/3$
2. Then stretched vertically by $32$
3. Then translated vertically by $1/3$

These transformations don't change the fact that the right branch is decreasing except that the right branch now starts at $-\frac{7}{3}$, instead of $0$.